# how to create mpq with stormlib

Tags: c++, file, package

How to create a mpq file with StormLib？ I have download StormLib and compiled it, In StormLib.h, I find a function: `SFileCreateArchive(const TCHAR * szMpqName, DWORD dwCreateFlags, DWORD dwMaxFileCount, HANDLE * phMpq)`, but I can not understand the last parameter `HANDLE* phMpq`, I think create a file need a parameter `fileName`, and it return a `HANDLE*` to hold the file, but `HANDLE* phMpq` is a in parameter, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
```

{
    cout <<"StormLib Version : "<

```
HANDLE mpqFile;
if (SFileCreateArchive(L"MPQ_File.data", MPQ_CREATE_SIGNATURE | MPQ_CREATE_ARCHIVE_V4, 1024, &mpqFile))
{
    cout << "created a mpq" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "faild to create" << endl;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
```

}